# Problem with using a Class in complex numbers calculator project

Tags: python, oop, complex-numbers

I am Thomas and I am a computer science student. For my latest OOP project in Python I've been trying to do a simple complex numbers calculator.

My task involves making a 2- class project in Python

First is the class has 3 methods:

1st - create a complex number
2nd - display a complex number
3rd - erase the complex number

Second class has four methods: add, subtract, multiply and divide.
I've made first class and it's methods and I think they work fine on a basic level ( of course the code is primitive and it needs a lot of work :( )

I've stumbled upon a problem with the second class. I can't properly use methods: add, subtract, multiply and divide.
I'd like mathematical methods to use previously created two complex numbers, but i can't find the way to correctly finish my task.

Any help is appreaciated. Thank you !

My code:

```
class Complex (object):
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary

    def create_number(self):
        self.real = (float(input("Enter a real part of the complex number")))
        self.imaginary = (float(input("Enter an imaginary part of the complex number")))
        return Complex(self.real, self.imaginary)

    def display_number(self):
        print(f"Your complex number is: {Complex(self.real, self.imaginary)}")

    def erase_number(self):
        (self.real, self.imaginary) = (0, 0)
        print(f"Number is erased: {(self.real, self.imaginary)}")

    def __str__(self):
        if type(self.real) == int and type(self.imaginary) == int:
            if self.imaginary >= 0:
                return '%d+%di' % (self.real, self.imaginary)
            elif self.imaginary < 0:
                return '%d%di' % (self.real, self.imaginary)
        else:
            if self.imaginary >= 0:
                return '%f+%fi' % (self.real, self.imaginary)
            elif self.imaginary < 0:
               return '%f%fi' % (self.real, self.imaginary)


class Calculator(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary

    def __add__(self, other):
        result_real = self.real+other.real
        result_imaginary = self.imaginary+other.imaginary
        result = Complex(result_real, result_imaginary)
        return result

    def __sub__(self, other):
        result_real = self.real-other.real
        result_imaginary = self.imaginary-other.imaginary
        result = Complex(result_real, result_imaginary)
        return result

    def __mul__(self, other):
        result_real = (self.real*other.real-self.imaginary*other.imaginary)
        result_imaginary = (self.real*other.imaginary+other.real*self.imaginary)
        result = Complex(result_real, result_imaginary)
        return result

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        result_real = float(float(self.real*other.real+self.imaginary*other.imaginary)/float(other.real*other.real+other.imaginary*other.imaginary))
        result_imaginary = float(float(other.real*self.imaginary-self.real*other.imaginary)/float(other.real*other.real+other.imaginary*other.imaginary))
        result = Complex(result_real, result_imaginary)
        return result


c1 = Complex(0, 0)
c2 = Complex(0, 0)

calc1 = Calculator(0, 0)
calc2= Calculator(0, 0)

choice = 1
while choice != 0:
    print("0. Exit")
    print("1. Construction of a complex number 1")
    print("2. Construction of a complex number 2")
    print("3. Display complex number 1")
    print("4. Display complex number 2")
    print("5. Erase complex number 1")
    print("6. Erase complex number 2")
    print("7. Addition")
    print("8. Subtraction")
    print("9. Multiplication")
    print("10. Division")
    choice = int(input("Enter choice: "))

    if choice == 1:
        print("Result: ", c1.create_number())
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Result: ", c2.create_number())
    elif choice == 3:
        print("Result: ", c1.display_number())
    elif choice == 4:
        print("Result: ", c2.display_number())
    elif choice == 5:
        print("Result: ", c1.erase_number())
    elif choice == 6:
        print("Result: ", c2.erase_number())
    elif choice == 7:
        print("Result: ", calc1.__add__(calc2))
    elif choice == 8:
        print("Result: ", calc1.__sub__(calc2))
    elif choice == 9:
        print("Result: ", calc1.__mul__(calc2))
    elif choice == 10:
        print("Result: ", calc1.__truediv__(calc2))
    elif choice == 0:
        print("Exiting!")
    else:
        print("Invalid choice!!")
```

Comment: "I can't properly use methods: add, ..." - what is your problem exactly?

Comment: For example when I am using the choice 7 in my if loop, the __add__ method returns the value of 0.0. I can't find a way to create a proper Calculator object, or perhaps the code needs changing cause i can't find a way to fix the problem.

Comment: Some general advice on approaching OOP: try to model relationships as they are in the real world. In this case: A user will only have one calculator, and the calculator should create/remember any numbers that the user may input

Comment: Thank you, it's a valuable advice. Sadly, for now, I struggle for my code to work, but in the future my code will mirror real life rules :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relationship between Calculator and Complex objects at the moment. The real/imaginary attributes of the Calculator are initialized to 0, but never updated.

One approach to fix this would be to initialize the Calculator with a reference to the Complex object:

```
class Calculator(object):
    def __init__(self, complex_number):
        self.complex_number = complex_number

    def __add__(self, other):
        result_real = self.complex_number.real+other.complex_number.real
        result_imaginary = self.complex_number.imaginary+other.complex_number.imaginary
        result = Complex(result_real, result_imaginary)
        return result
    # other methods should be modified as appropriate..


c1 = Complex(0, 0)
c2 = Complex(0, 0)

calc1 = Calculator(c1)
calc2= Calculator(c2)
```

The user will update `c1` when calling create_number, and the Calculator will have a reference to that (now updated) Complex object when the user calls `add`.

Comment: When I remove the real and imaginary parameters from the Calculator method, my other methods from the Calculator class: add, sub. mul, truediv are unusable, because the methods use them for calculating. Could you please show me how a proper 'add' class should look like? Also I've noticed that the name of a complex object you added to the class starts with the lowercase letter. I know, that by the rules,  it should be lowercase, but the object i've created starts with the uppercase. Will it work with lowercase?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show what the __add__ method would look like.The lowercase attribute-name should work, but I've changed that as well to make it more obvious that it refers to something else.

Comment: It finally worked. I fidled with the complex_number parameter before but yday I just gave up and decided to ask for help. I don't know how long it would take me to understand the issue. Thank you ! Now I'll try to do the thing you mentioned earlier: 'A user will only have one calculator, and the calculator should create/remember any numbers that the user may input'

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer your question, but is valid knowledge either way.

The `__add__` family of methods ('magic methods') are intended for python's internal use only.

When you write `a + b`, python will check if `a` happens to have an `__add__` method, and use that, or if not use `b`'s `__radd__` method.

So one should simply 'use' the methods indirectly: `print("Result: ", calc1 + calc2)`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read about it :) In my case print("Result: ", calc1 + calc2) would stil be 0.0 because I can't create a proper Calculator() object to use previously created complex numbers

Comment: Ok, I understand what you meant by " When you write a + b, python will check if a happens to have an __add__ method, and use that, or if not use b's __radd__ method." Thank you, that's a valuable lesson.